# Stata: Count if non-missing across row for certain range

Tags: sum, stata, missing-data

I am trying to count the number of times an event occurred before a particular age. I have data that shows the age at each event over a lifetime (age_at_event1-age_at_event3), as well as the age at which I am no longer interested in counting such events (stop_age). I would like to create a variable (sum_event) which counts the number of times the event of interest occurred prior to the stop age. An example:

```
ID    age_event1    age_event2    age_event3    stop_age  sum_event
 1         10          17           45             34        2         
 2         23          31           32             54        3   
 3         25          55            .             32        1    
 4         21           .            .             22        1
```

How do I create the appropriate sum_event variable?

Comment: For future questions, please show attempted code reflecting the research effort that is always expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to `reshape` your data, then you can loop over variables and count:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
ID    age_event1    age_event2    age_event3    stop_age  sum_event
 1         10          17           45             34        2         
 2         23          31           32             54        3   
 3         25          55            .             32        1    
 4         21           .            .             22        1
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen sumevent2 = 0
foreach var of varlist age_event1 age_event2 age_event3 {
    replace sumevent2 = sumevent2 + (`var' < stop_age)
}

list
```

For numbered variables that follow some pattern, you can try something like:

```
<snip>

gen sumevent2 = 0
forvalues i = 1/3 {
    replace sumevent2 = sumevent2 + (age_event`i' < stop_age)
}
```

Another way with `reshape`:

```
*----- what you want -----

<snip>

reshape long age_event, i(ID) j(j)
bysort ID: egen sumevent2 = total(age_event < stop_age)
reshape wide // if you really need to go back to wide

list
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you. Any chance you could tell me how to avoid having to type out the age_event variables one by one? Despite my example I actually have dozens of age_event variables. I know the forval command comes into play, but I'm not sure of the specifics.

Comment: Try `age_event*` but make sure you really want to include all variables that start in this way. I also added the `forvalues` solution to the answer.

Comment: http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046 reviews technique here.